# Child processes remain after quitting screen

Tags: unix, process, gnu-screen

I'm seeing some strange screen behavior on OSX. When I quit screen, child processes are not killed.

```
$ screen
$ tail -f (or some long running process inside screen)
```

Then, I kill the current screen window with `^a k` or terminate screen entirely with `^a ^\` and it appears everything went well:

```
$ [screen is terminating]
```

However, `tail -f` is still running (with a PPID of 1). Why is it orphaned instead of killed? Is there a setting/flag that alters this behavior? I've tried this under Ubuntu and screen behaves as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: It works as expected for me under OS X 10.6. Are you running /usr/bin/screen, or some other installed version?

Comment: Yep, /usr/bin/screen and I tried with/without a .screenrc

Comment: Has `tail` become a zombie or something like that? Theoretically once you close the screen, its tty dies and `tail` will loose its stdio and just die. If it hasn't died, it might be waiting for some kernel space stuff to be cleared.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but `tail` doesn't go away. I don't think they're zombies, because I can kill them fine (and they are still running with a parent PID of 1).

Comment: I ran into the same issue and switched to `tmux`, which does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen where a pseudo-terminal's process will remain until it receives input.  To test this case, after you see the lingering process in the `ps` list, send a `wall` and a short message.  The process should then disappear.